# Google+ sign in protocols

Tags: php, https, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I started this PHP-tutorial on my Debian7/nginx server for setting up a Googleplus Sign in.
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php?hl=it

I've done everything, but when I go to the mysite.me/gplus-quickstart-php/signin.php page and click on the button, it asks me to log in, i log, and then in console appear an error:

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://mysite.me" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

I don't have an SSL certificate, so on my server i can't use https...
Google Sign in can't be used without a secure connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

I have updated my `REDIRECT URIS`, in the Google console.